# How can I get the cumulative sum between a predefined number of days in SAS EG

Tags: date, sas, cumulative-sum

I would like to find a way to calculate the cumulative sum between a predefined number of days.

Just to clarify, I am looking to calculate the cumulative sum between days. Those can be consecutive (e.g. 03AUG and 04AUG) or not (e.g. 04AUG and 06AUG).

Below the data I have:

```
data have;
input ID $ DT:date9. Amount;
format DT date9.;
datalines;
A 09JUL2021 3600
A 03AUG2021 456
A 04AUG2021 33
A 06AUG2021 235
A 07AUG2021 100
A 09AUG2021 86
A 12AUG2021 456
A 24AUG2021 22
A 25AUG2021 987
A 26AUG2021 916
A 27AUG2021 81
;
run;
```

I want to be able to create a new variable that shows the cumulative amount between 2 or more days.
I should be able every time to select if I want the cumulative amount between 2 days, or 3 days and so on.

Below the data I want, when I select to calculate the sum between two days:

```
data what_I_want;
input ID $ DT:date9. Amount Sum_Between_Days;
format DT date9.;
datalines;
A 09JUL2021 3600 0
A 03AUG2021 456 0
A 04AUG2021 33 489
A 06AUG2021 235 268
A 07AUG2021 100 335
A 09AUG2021 86 186
A 12AUG2021 456 0
A 24AUG2021 22 0
A 25AUG2021 987 0
A 26AUG2021 916 1925
A 27AUG2021 81 1984
;
run;
```

Below the data I want when I select to calculate the sum between 3 days:

```
data what_I_want;
input ID $ DT:date9. Amount Sum_Between_Days;
format DT date9.;
datalines;
A 09JUL2021 3600 0
A 03AUG2021 456 0
A 04AUG2021 33 0
A 06AUG2021 235 724
A 07AUG2021 100 0
A 09AUG2021 86 186
A 12AUG2021 456 0
A 24AUG2021 22 0
A 25AUG2021 987 0
A 26AUG2021 916 0
A 27AUG2021 81 2006
;
run;
```

Hopefully, I make sense, but please let me know if not..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your examples, there's dates which are not consecutive (e.g. 04AUG and 06AUG) yet they form the sum for 06AUG. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks, please see the amended post. Basically, I am looking to calculate the cumulative sum between a predefined number of days. Those can be consecutive (e.g. 03AUG and 04AUG) or not consecutive (e.g. 04AUG and 06AUG).

Comment: For your  WANT data set please explain why the sum is 724 on day 4 and the first record of 3600 is ignored. That doesn't seem to align with your statement of not consecutive.

Comment: Thanks, That's the case when I want to calculate the sum between 3 days. So, between 03Aug and 06Aug the amounts are: 456 + 33 + 235 = 724. The first record (09Jul) will not be ignored only if any of the next days will be in the range between 10Jul and 13Jul.

Comment: So I would like something like that:
Find the cumulative amount between 3 dates (days):
First date is 09Jul, is there any days between 09Jul and 13Jul? No.
Second date is 03Aug, is there any days between 04Aug and 06Aug? Yes.
And so on..

Comment: So the first record is always ignored? This likely won't scale to your actual data unless you provide clear rules.

Comment: But that isn't 3 days., is it an attempt at 3 business days or weekdays?

Comment: If the second record was 10Jul, it will not be ignored.

Comment: It is an attempt at weekdays. Between 03Aug and 06Aug is four days, you are right.

Comment: I tried solving this issue a number of ways, but the difficult aspect of this is that you need to constantly check if you've exceeded that number of days and reset the count so that it starts again for the next set of values. It's certainly possible, but it'll require a few tricks that I haven't quite been able to work out yet. Very interesting use case. It would make a good bonus test question somewhere!

Comment: I know it is quite challenging. I have solved it by iterating each day for each ID, but as you can imagine with big data this method is not efficient.

Comment: Can you elaborate why in the "sum between two days" the cumulative amount for 25AUG2021 is not 1009 (22+987)?

Comment: Also, the "sum between two days" implies a different logic than the "sum of three days". For the former its a cumulative sum whereas the latter seems to be some kind of binning?